# Is there any method for PaymentResponse api to check response of payment?

Tags: javascript, payment-method, payment-request-api

As we can check the status that either payment api is supported or not. Using window object:

`window.PaymentRequest`

Is there any way to check after payment what is status of PaymentResponse using only **window** object?

I don't have access to the code of  payment and I am trying to check status using window object only.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the response back. See this

```
// global
const { PaymentRequest } = window;

// Selectors
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

// config
const paymentMethods = [
  {
    supportedMethods: ['basic-card']
  }
];

const paymentDetails = {
  total: {
    label: 'What you pay',
    amount: {
      currency: 'USD',
      value: 10
    }
  }
};


const paymentRequest = PaymentRequest && new PaymentRequest(
  paymentMethods,
  paymentDetails
);

const addItemToCart = ({target}) => {
  paymentRequest
  .show()
  .then(paymentResponse => {
    return paymentResponse.complete().then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });
  })
  .catch(reason => console.error(`Error occurred: ${reason}`));
};

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', addItemToCart));
```

Here's a codepen link

https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/yodVzw?editors=1111

Comment: I have mentioned that I don't have access to code. I want to check using window object only

Comment: Then theres no way if thats the case then. Thats due to security reasons.

Comment: I guess there is way because they provides the support for paymentrequest so may be there is way to check only for either payment is done or not. And this may not be cause any security issue

Comment: But you need to have access to your code in order to do it